# Populate textbox from sql based on other txtboxes values in form

Tags: php, sql, ajax, mysqli

I am doing a registration page where the one input textbox should be populated based on 2 other input textboxes.

```
tblEntries
Id; firstname; lastname; age; gender; categories 

tblCategories
Id; categories; age_from; age_to, gender
Data inserted:  1; Veteran_male; 20; 30; male

frmEntries.php is populated with tblEntries data onload already using localstorage.
(may look like this
Firstname=Peter
Lastname=Trump
Age=25
Gender=male
Categories= ?(from sql)



include("conn.php");
include("categories.php");

<input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" />
    <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="" />
    <input id="age" type="text" name="age" value="" />
    <input id="gender" type="text" name="gender" value="" />
 <input id="categories" type="text" name="categories" value="<?php echo $output; ?>" />
```

(the 25 fall in between 20 and 30 in the tblCategories and the gender is shown in both tables)

```
categories.php

 <php?
        include ('conn.php');
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
  $age = $_POST["age"];
 $result = $con->query("SELECT categories FROM tblCategories WHERE '$age' BETWEEN age_from AND age_to AND gender='$gender'”); 
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $output = '';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
         $output = $row["categories"];
        }
        echo($output);-   //(to be populated inside the frmEntries and the 
        “categories” field onload)
        }
        ?>
```

Should i use Ajax with a button?

```
<script>
$('#updateBtn').click(function(e){
    //to disable the click from going to next page
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax(
         'categories.php', function(data){

               $('#categories').val(data);
         }
    );
});
</script>
```

Please advise on how to do this. Should I rather use a button to populate "categories" after onload? I get variable not find errors

Comment: I am confused by your question. You have flagged it as ajax yet there is a post transition between the 2 scripts. What has this got to do with onload? I don't understand what you mean by "I get variable not find errors". If you want to provide a list of applicable "categories" why are you presenting them in a text box where they can be edited rather than as a select or radio buttons or checkboxes? If you want to populate the registration page without a navigation event, where is your javascript?

Comment: Your question is not pretty clear, although I think you need onBlur event to send your age via Ajax to your categories.php and populate the categories input with return data ( if it is single) else you need a select and loop through your result.